# Changing SKPhysicsBody while changing SKSpriteNode position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I've got quite simple game. It's like the classic Labyrinth game which uses accelereometer but user is also able to change the size of the rectangle using 3D Touch.

The player's node is rectangle which moves thanks to the world's physics which gets data from the accelerometer (nothing special here):

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
    if let motionData = data{
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: motionData.acceleration.x * 7, dy: motionData.acceleration.y * 7)
    }
}
```

and touchesMoved :

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
            let maxForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce
            let force = touch.force

            let forceValue = force/maxForce

            player.size = CGSize(width: 26-forceValue*16, height: 26-forceValue*16)
            player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    resetSize()
}

func resetSize(){
    player.size = CGSize(width: 26, height: 26)
}
```

So when I was changing player's size it worked fine: the node was moving around the screen based on device's orientation and while pressing harder it was getting smaller. The problem was that the physicsBody (I've set `view.showsPhysics = true` in GameViewController.swift) was always the same so I've added `player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)` but now when I'm pressing the screen the player's node resizes but it also stops moving. How to change the node's size and physicsBody simultaneously and keep it in motion?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the `physicsBody` you lost all physics parameters that invoved your previous `physicsBody`: you can copy `velocity` or `angularVelocity` or other available parameters but it's not enough, you will never have a continuity because the `SpriteKit` framework (on the actual version) don't have this option: dynamically change the `physicsBody` during the game.

You can also change the scaling of you node to modify the `physicsBody` but you always lost physics variables as for example the accumulated speed due to gravity : this happened because `SpriteKit` change automatically the `physicsBody` during the scaling to create others bodies without preserve the accumulated properties.

So my advice is to create a kind of "freezing time" when you touch your ball, where you can change you `physicsBody` when the ball is stopped.

Comment: People who downvote should demonstrate a solution (but a real physic vars time real propagation, not a faked..) and try to explain their  opposite idea about my statements to help the OP.

Comment: What do you mean by freezing time? Should I stop the movement when I want to change the size and after the size is ok continue with movement of the ball?

Comment: It's only an idea, but you can find other modes: you can create the effect like the "Matrix" movie scene around it (reduce music speed and all the movements of your game elements only for this state..)

Comment: Yeah, it's a solution but not what I've expected. I'm quite new to Swift so maybe someone will post a solution.

Comment: Have you a fixed big size to reach or could you resize your ball as you wish? Because another idea could be to make an hidden big ball that make the same thing of your ball then you can pass from a ball to the biggest (or the opposite case) making an animation to fadeIn the big and fadeOut the little..Anyway, good luck for your game :-)